# Changing the Selector style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making some changes to an Xcode project from [this](https://github.com/SvenTiigi/VanMoofKit) GitHub repo. I was trying to change the selector menu to a segmented style, but I wasn't able to get it working. The part of the selector I want to change is below. Can someone help me?

```
import SwiftUI
import VanMoofKit

// MARK: - SpeedLimitCard

extension BikeView {
    
    /// The SpeedLimitCard
    struct SpeedLimitCard {
        
        @EnvironmentObject
        private var bike: VanMoof.Bike
        
    }
    
}

// MARK: - View

extension BikeView.SpeedLimitCard: View {
    
    /// The content and behavior of the view.
    var body: some View {
        BikeView.Card(
            placeholderValue: .europe,
            title: "Speed Limit",
            systemImage: "speedometer",
            provider: {
                try await self.bike.speedLimit
            },
            publisher: self.bike.speedLimitPublisher,
            content: { speedLimit in
                Gauge(
                    value: speedLimit.measurement.value,
                    in: 0...37
                ) {
                    Text(verbatim: speedLimit.measurement.unit.symbol)
                } currentValueLabel: {
                    Text(verbatim: .init(Int(speedLimit.measurement.value)))
                }
                .scaleEffect(1.4)
                .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)
                .tint(.teal)
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            },
            actions: { currentSpeedLimit in
                ForEach(VanMoof.Bike.SpeedLimit.allCases, id: \.self) { speedLimit in
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            try await self.bike.set(speedLimit: speedLimit)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label {
                            Text(
                                verbatim: "\(speedLimit.localizedString) (\(speedLimit.measurement.formatted()))"
                            )
                        } icon: {
                            if currentSpeedLimit == speedLimit {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        
    }
    
}

private extension VanMoof.Bike.SpeedLimit {
    
    var localizedString: String {
        switch self {
        case .europe:
            return "Europe"
        case .unitedStates:
            return "United States"
        case .japan:
            return "Japan"
        }
    }
}
```

Adding `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())`, I expected it to change to the segmented pickerstyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Picker` in the code you supplied, so setting `.pickerStyle` is probably not going to have any effect... unless this is something that is supported by the third-party library you are using (not familiar to me).

Here is a standalone example of how a segmented picker could be formed using the options that you were using before:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var currentSpeedLimit = SpeedLimit.europe

    var body: some View {
        Picker("SpeedLimit", selection: $currentSpeedLimit) {
            ForEach(SpeedLimit.allCases, id: \.self) { speedLimit in
                Text(
                    verbatim: "\(speedLimit.localizedString) (\(speedLimit.measurement.formatted()))"
                )
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .fixedSize() // stops it expanding more than necessary
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: currentSpeedLimit) { oldVal, newVal in
            // Task {
            //     try await self.bike.set(speedLimit: newVal)
            // }
            print("\(newVal) selected")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picker]

You could try plugging this `Picker` into your code to replace the `ForEach` being passed using the parameter `actions` to `BikeView.Card`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I’ve tried it and it the text syncs but the only thing is i couldn’t get the action which sets the speedlimit on the bike to work

Comment: Does the ```.onChange``` callback get called and can you print the selected value? If so, you need to investigate how to apply this to the instance of ```VanMoof.Bike```, I don't think I can help you much there.

Comment: Ive got it to work, thanks! I’m thinking about publishing the app on the AppStore when it’s done. Do you want to get mentioned for helping?

Comment: I'm pleased to hear you got it working. You don't need to mention me in the credits thanks, although you might like to mention StackOverflow more generally. But if the answer helped, I hope you'll consider accepting it and/or giving it an upvote ;)